# Whats the way to compare dates in c++

Tags: c++, date

Whats the best way to compare dates in c++ which are made into a structure
that has a day,month and year variable i.e how to check that 30 days have passed since a event and so on. I personally found that when comparing 2 dates in the same year I make both dates into "days-dates" using a array that holds the day count of all the months of the year and then convert the dates into days and do the calculations I need. Is there a easier way to compare the dates ?

Comment: [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) will be useful

Comment: If you're checking durations, then there's really no good alternative to converting to a single date number. There are multiple standards to choose from, probably the most popular is [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the number of elapsed seconds since 1/1/1970. You might want to see what your available libraries support.

Comment: Which date/time library are you using? Have you done any research into solutions?

Comment: Id depens how impelmented date. C++ many years has not standard here

Comment: @MarkRansom: If you want anything better than "number of seconds", you have a lot of work to do to make a UNIX timestamp diff useful.

Comment: @JacekCz: C++ several years has standard here :) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I said it was the most popular, I didn't say anything as to whether it was most appropriate for this question. Which is impossible because the question doesn't have many details.

Comment: Boost has a date and time library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/date_time.html

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I keep forgetting about `chrono`, never had a chance to use it. That would probably make a good answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes :) But cant see applications with it. In reality CDateTime, TDate :Qt::Something, char[8] or integer since 1970

Comment: @JacekCz: 1970 was quite a while ago. If you want to see an application that uses modern technology (including `std::chrono`), apply for a job at my company and if you're lucky you'll get to work on one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very good [C++11/14 library for handling dates](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html)<sup>1</sup>.  It allows you to have `{year, month, day}` structures (called `date::year_month_day`), and `{count-of-days}` structures (called `sys_days`).  It also allows easy and efficient conversions between these two structures.  And naturally there are comparison operators.

The entire library is essentially an extension of `<chrono>` into calendar types.

Video introduction found here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo

[Lots of example code here](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes).

Here is a detailed explanation of the underlying algorithms to convert between the `{year, month, day}` structure and the `{count-of-days}` structure:

http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Here are some date creation and comparison examples for both field (`year_month_day`) and serial (`sys_days`) data structures:

```
#include "date.h"

int
main()
{
    using namespace date::literals;

    // create and compare {year, month, day} structures
    constexpr auto ymd1 = 2017_y/jan/21;
    constexpr auto ymd2 = ymd1 + date::months{15};
    static_assert(ymd2 > ymd1, "ymd2 is 15 months after ymd1");
    static_assert(ymd2 == 2018_y/apr/21, "ymd2 is 2018-04-21");

    // create and compare {count_of_days} structures
    constexpr date::sys_days sd2 = ymd2;
    static_assert(sd2 == ymd2, "sd2 is the same day as ymd2");
    static_assert(sd2.time_since_epoch().count() == 17642, "sd2 is day 17642");
    constexpr date::sys_days sd1 = sd2 - date::days{465};
    static_assert(sd1 < sd2, "sd1 is 465 days before sd2");
    static_assert(sd1.time_since_epoch().count() == 17177, "sd1 is day 17177");
    static_assert(sd1 == 2017_y/jan/11, "sd1 is 2017-01-11");
}
```

The `constexpr` / `static_assert` requires a fully conforming C++14 compiler.  For C++11, remove the `constexpr` and change `static_assert` to `assert` (and eliminate the `static_assert` message).

`date::sys_days` is a typedef for the `chrono::time_point`:

```
time_point<system_clock, duration<int, ratio<86400>>
```

The above example code requires only `"date.h"`, and no other C++ source files (no installation).  There is also available a [timezone library at this same github location](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), but that does require some installation.

---

<sup>1</sup> I am the principal author of this library.

Comment: It _is_ a very good library. Not sure how I feel about you introducing your own library as "a very good library" without explicitly disclosing that you wrote it, though!

Comment: More people are contributing to as time goes on: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/graphs/contributors :-)  I would have a hard time keeping it portable by myself.  Yes, I am the principal author.  James Beach just ported it to VS-2017 yesterday.

Comment: Maybe a slight tweak to the opening sentence of your answer is called for :)

Comment: Thou your library from my quick glance and low knowledge is useful, but the library has to be already pre installed in visuals studio 2015

Comment: @Blackwolf23:  The part you asked about (comparing dates), is a single-header-only file (date.h) which needs no installation on any platform, and is known to work on VS-2015 (and VS-2013, and just recently ported to VS-2017).  If you need timezone support, here are the installation instructions: https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation (includes Windows-specific instructions).

Answer (score 1):

For what you describe, the standard C style routines are probably going to work best: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c

Here is a rough example using C style coding

```
#include <ctime>

const int SECONDS_PER_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;

tm day1;
memset( &day1, 0, sizeof(day1) );
day1.tm_year = 2016 - 1900; // tm_year is the years since 1900 
                            // so to represent 2016, the value is 116.
day1.tm_mon  = 0;
day1.tm_mday = 20;

time_t day1a = mktime( &day1 );

tm day2;
memset( &day2, 0, sizeof(day2) );
day1.tm_year = 2008 - 1900; 
day1.tm_mon  = 0;
day1.tm_mday = 20;

time_t day2a = mktime( &day2 );

double day_delta = difftime( day1, day2 ); // returns number of seconds
double days_past = (day_delta / SECONDS_PER_DAY)
```

This is standard and will work on everywhere.

N.B. the POSIX standard defines `time_t` as an integral type

Comment: This probably doesn't pass code review in my team these days. Also it does not account for leap seconds, to the best of my knowledge (although it should be aware of other human timing oddities).

Comment: It wouldn't pass code review with me either. As I said, it's a rough example to show the general usage and introduce him to `tm`, `mktime()`, `time_t`, et al. He's asking about measuring days elapsed. I doubt he cares to measure it to seconds, so leap seconds don't play into it.

Comment: It will after 86400 of them ^_^ I'm curious as to why you wrote an answer recommending a solution that you would reject in your own work. Ah well.

Comment: The example code here, I would reject. Using these routines, I would not.

Comment: Ok then to be clear it's both that would not be accepted in my team

Comment: I'm glad you don't work on my team. These routines are perfectly adequate for the use mentioned in the question. The're not just familiar, but in the standard and supported everywhere that matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to implement it yourself then simplest way is to keep date as a single integer - [Julian day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) As you can see on the article calculation from month/day/year into Julian day and back is pretty trivial (from computer perspective of course). When you keep dates as a single number calculate difference in days or compare them is trivial. Or if you say that it is already implemented as a structure you can convert your dates into Julian day on the fly (or keep mutable field to cache that value).